# border-image without spacing on bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, border-image

I want to have no space in the bottom, I already added margin-bottom:0px; without success, I figured out that without the border-image atribute the space disapears... how can I solve this?

```
css code: .footer2 {

  text-align: center;
  display:  block;
  clear: both; 

  background-repeat:no-repeat;




/*css border completa*/
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 32px 37px 40px;
  -moz-border-image: url(../imgs/video_frame.png) 32 37 40 repeat;
  -webkit-border-image: url(../imgs/video_frame.png) 32 37 40 repeat;
  -o-border-image: url(../imgs/video_frame.png) 32 37 40 repeat;
  border-image: url(../imgs/video_frame.png) 32 37 40 fill repeat;

    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;


   background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  /*padding: 1% 1.5%; */
  width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
  font-family: 'barthowheelregular';}



HTML: <div class="footer2 spacer5">
                    <h1 class="texto_footer">Minimon - Designed by  <a href="http://schismatick.com/" class="texto_footer" target="_blank">Schismatick</a> - Copyright 2015</h1>
                  </div>
```

Comment: * {padding-bottom : 0px, margin-bottom: 0px} <br/> Also check the height of the container

Comment: I've tried it before, doesn't work... the strange thing about this is when I use a simple div without any border-image the space bellow disapears...

Comment: the image was a png background and add some transparent pixels.. duh. problem solved :P

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding correctly, If your looking to decrease the space below the `<h1>` element but still within the `.footer2` div then try messing around with the `line-height` attribute.

Comment: Tried it too before... doesn't work... yes I want to decrease the space below the frame image, here is a print: http://schismatick.com/img/border_space.jpg